# How to change specific column data in the datatable according to some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable, datarow

I have the following case :

I add row by row to `Datatable dtItems` according to the user data entry through a button .

One of the columns in my data table is `Hours` , and i wanna to achieve the following conditions :

- 1- for each user the total hours is less than or equal 5.
- 2- the default :if the user enter one row then hours = 5

  if he enters two rows then make the first one 4 and the second one is 1

  if he enters three rows then make the first one is 3 and the second is 1 and the third is 1.

  etc.
- 3-the maximum number of rows for each user is 5.

LIKE this:

user_id  |    name  |     hours

---

323    |     jo   |    3

323    |     jo   |    1

323    |     jo   |    1

324    |     jack |    4

324    |     jack |    1

---

```
DataTable dtItems = GetDataTable();
DataRow dr = dtItems.NewRow();
dr["emp_num"] = txt_EmpNum.Text.Trim();
dr["name"] = txt_EmpName.Text.Trim();
dr["hours"] = 5;
dtItems.Rows.Add(dr);

GV_Employee.DataSource = dtItems;
GV_Employee.DataBind();

Session["ItemDT"] = dtItems;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't know how to change the DataRow's `Hour` fields accordingly before you insert them into database.

The only what you need to know is the new `hour` of the first DataRow, the others get 1 hour:

```
var firstHour = 5 + 1 - dtItems.Rows.Count; //where 5 is your MaxCount
for (var i = 0; i < dtItems.Rows.Count; i++) {
    if (i == 0) 
        dtItems.Rows[i]["hours"] = firstHour;
    else
        dtItems.Rows[i]["hours"] = 1;
}
```

To prevent users from inserting more than 5 rows, you only need to check for `dtItems.Rows.Count < 5` before you insert the new.

---

**Edit**: If you need it to be calculated for every `emp_num` in the `DataTable` as commented:

```
var q = from r in dtItems.AsEnumerable()
        group r by r["emp_num"];

foreach(var empGrp in q){
    var rows=empGrp.ToList();
    var firstHour = 5 + 1 - rows.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++){
        if (i == 0)
            rows[i]["hours"] = firstHour;
        else
            rows[i]["hours"] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot , hmmmm no , i wanna `all employees` but the conditions are per `emp_num`, please look to the table above , i edit it to clarify the idea

Comment: @just_name: edited my answer again, i think that should work now. Otherwise you should now know where to fiddle around ;)